# How to get x-mfp-analytics-api-key in MF8 to export data?

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst, swagger-ui, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to use swagger ui to export data from analytics console using Analytics Rest API as given in thew tutorials . How to get x-mfp-analytics-api-key for the app in local?

```
https://example.com:9080/analytics-service/v3/export
```

Answer (score 0):

x-mfp-analytics-api-key is the ElasticSearch index name to which data is posted.
If you work with the swagger UI, it is easier to figure out the headers and url params.

Answer (score 0):

Collect a packet trace between the runtime server and the analytics server. You will see that header. I do not believe there is a way to get the header on the client side.

Comment: Yes I am unable to get it.